# How can I change the Skype icon in the wingpanel to match the default style?

Tags: applications, wingpanel, icons, luna, skype

It'd be nicer if the Skype icon was smaller and white. Here's how it looks right now:

[image: skype icon]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**This solution will work on elementary OS 0.3 (Freya) and 0.4 (Loki), Luna users should follow [PNG's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/99/22)**

To change the skype icon (and many other) you have to install the [elementary+ icon theme](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus).

This theme is a community maintained addition to elementary OS's default icon theme. It contains icons for several third party applications that resemble elementary OS's style.

Add this PPA (Personal Package Archive) to your sources:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementaryplus
```

After the elementary+ icon theme and the patched sni-qt got successfully installed, open elementary+ Configurator in your Slingshot (applications menu), select Skype and hit Apply.

[image]

Restart Skype and you should have a nice white Skype indicator icon

[image]

---

Update:

Testing in Loki: avoid activating the core icon theme (first entry in the program window), as it disables some icons (like Synaptic).

Comment: I'm getting an error `E: Unable to locate package elementaryplus` :(

Comment: @waldyrious either you didn't add the repository or you forgot to run ``sudo apt-get update``

Comment: @Rafael I ran all the commands exactly as provided above: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install elementaryplus`

Comment: @waldyrious oh, according to your screenshot you are using elementary OS 0.2 Luna. elementary+ officially supports only Freya (elementary OS 0.3)

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for adding the clarification in the answer. I'll accept the answer anyway.

Comment: Marvelous! Just one little thing... a restart of skype may be necessary.

Comment: @ikaro thank you for your input, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: @waldyrious take a look at PNGs answer, this should work at your Luna install. I've added a link to his answer, so that all Luna users should find it quickly.

Comment: I ran all of the commands and successfully installed elementary+ and set the new icon using the configurator, but it didn't work. Is 0.2.6-0ubuntu1.1 (32 and 64-bit) the right sni-qt version? I'm on Freya.

Comment: @user42 no, this is the previous version of patched sni-qt. Did you install elementary+ through the PPA, and did you run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`afterwards? This PPA contains a newer version...

Comment: @Rafael yes, but it says `The following packages have been kept back:
  sni-qt sni-qt:i386`
Should I remove them and update again?

Comment: @user42 `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` should solve your problem... I'll forward this bug to cybre

Comment: @Rafael I've done this now, but `dpkg -l` still shows me: `rc sni-qt:amd64 0.2.6-0ubuntu1.1` . Same for i386. If I try to install sni-qt it tells me that I have unmet dependencies: `sni-qt : Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4+elementary3+r1~ubuntu0.3.1 is to be installed
`

Comment: I have the same issue as @user42

Comment: @user42 a new version of patched sni-qt got released tonight `0.2.7-eplus~74~ubuntu14.04.1`, try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again. If this doesn't work try to remove your current version of sni-qt first `sudo apt-get remove --purge sni-qt sni-qt:386` and then install it again `sudo apt-get install sni-qt sni-qt:386`.

Comment: @Rafael It still says that I have unmet dependencies (libqtgui4, like above)

Comment: @user42 I opened an [issue at GitHub](https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus/issues/204), we should continue our conversation in this thread.

Comment: Thanks for sorting this out for us @Rafael. I noticed the updated sni-qt in apt today. Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 8):

**Guide for Luna:**

After installing Skype, add this PPA which provides a patched [sni-qt](https://launchpad.net/sni-qt), and install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rpeshkov/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sni-qt
```

Then download and install the [skype-wrapper](https://github.com/rpeshkov/skype-wrapper) icon pack:

```
wget https://github.com/rpeshkov/skype-wrapper/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
(cd skype-wrapper-master/ && sudo ./install.sh elementary)
rm -rf skype-wrapper-master/
```

Restart Skype and enjoy ;)

[image: Skype indicator]

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a luna compatible patched sni-qt, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Thanks! Is this an icon pack you developed? If so, I'd ask you to host them somewhere with a permanent url (e.g. github?) so we can use command-line tools like curl/wget to download & extract them.

Comment: @waldyrious these icons I found on [GitHub](https://github.com/rpeshkov/skype-wrapper). And thank you for correcting my answer, I speak very bad English.

Comment: No problem @PNG. Btw you can accept the edit yourself, in case you didn't know :)