# Need help with changing the wingpanel icon of MegaSync Linux client

Tags: release-freya, wingpanel, icons

I love the app, it gives me 50GB free space, but the icon sucks. I have paper icons installed. And I want to change it to something that goes along with it. Can I manually change the icon to something of my choice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer. For anybody looking.
[rafael's](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/22/rafael) answer on the question [change skype icon wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-can-i-change-the-skype-icon-in-the-wingpanel-to-match-the-default-style).
Install elementary+. It works for megasync. :)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cybre/elementaryplus
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install elementaryplus
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up file manager and navigate to where the app is installed. My guess would be `/usr/bin`. Right click and go to properties. There should be an option to change the icon.

If not go to `/usr/share/application/`. In there find the .desktop for your app, open it with Audi privileges and update path to icon URL.

Comment: What I want to change is the wingpanel icon and not the slingshot icon.