# indicators on wingpanel

Tags: wingpanel

I am still in my customization process within this great distro and I am wondering if there is a way to get an better control of the indicators.
I reactivated the indicators, now I am getting two network indicator icons what I want to fix.
Also can someone tell me where I can find the icons for the indicators in order to get them changes?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how to remove gaps between icons in wing panel a tutorial

1 - Install the wingpanel indicator mentioned in previous post

2 - Download libayatana_compatibility.so.zip from here [libayatana_compatibility.so.zip](https://github-production-repository-file-5c1aeb.s3.amazonaws.com/144302344/3776351?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20200424%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200424T103942Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=6e7af642fc8bc0c37808998150422a2466f0e4dd1dfb20d26358dccb1a07243a&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&repo_id=144302344&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3Dlibayatana_compatibility.so.zip&response-content-type=application%2Fzip) and unzip it

Open terminal and go to Downloads

cd /home/username/Downloads

unzip libayatana_compatibility.so.zip

3 - Go To (with sudo) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

sudo -i

Type your sudo user password

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

4 - Backup your libayatana_compatibility.so

mv libayatana_compatibility.so libayatana_compatibility.backup

5 - Replace the libayatana_compatibility.so with the zipped one

cp /home/username/Downloads/libayatana-compatibility.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wingpanel/

6 - reboot

systemctl reboot

source

https://github.com/mdh34/elementary-indicators/issues/1

this works to me with no problem.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try... I am almost there where I want to be with that distro
any clue how I can change the icons of the indicators?
to get rid of the colored ones and have all in b/w? basically just a nice to have

Comment: You can try this solution: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-can-i-change-the-skype-icon-in-the-wingpanel-to-match-the-default-style

Comment: already found this
elementary plus seems to be down or not working on eOS 5.1

Comment: @dford I have found only this thread https://amp.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/cv6l23/how_to_customize_wingpanel_plank_in_elementary/ It seems that it depends on app developer and modified versions of wingpanel are old. I have found one thread on neowin however old and I do not recommend it. Maybe one day I will find out how to do that the safe way.

Comment: is there are valid and easy way to reduce the space between the indicators ?
I found some threads where I should change the .css file which seems not to be valid anymore on wingpanel

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is the only working way in the newest Elementary OS. I use it and it works.

Comment: I modified the main guide. It should be easier now.

Answer (score 1):

Ayatana indicators for apps , tlp, tlp UI , slimbook battery - works on DELL not only Slimbooks. It should work on all laptops.

Copy all bolded text below:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart && cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop ~/.config/autostart/ && sed -i 's/^OnlyShowIn.*/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;/' ~/.config/autostart/indicator-application.desktop && wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.3+r27+pkg17~ubuntu0.4.1.1_amd64.deb && systemctl reboot
```

then type in terminal

```
cd /home/yourusername


sudo vi indicators.sh
```

press ins button to go into insert mode

press ctrl+shift+v to paste

press esc button to escape insert mode

type

```
:wq
```

this will write and quit the file

then type

```
sudo chmod +x indicators.sh
```

then type

```
./indicators.sh
```

script will run, install ayatana and restart the machine

Works in hera 5.1

For double wi-fi icon

```
mv /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.old
```

Additional gift for battery saver. Requires tlp to work

```
sudo apt update



sudo apt install tlp



sudo add-apt-repository ppa:slimbook/slimbook



sudo apt update



sudo apt install slimbookbattery



sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

If you need also tlp UI

then type in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/apps



sudo apt install tlpui
```

---

to remove slimbook battery and app indicator

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove slimbookbattery gnome-shell-extension-appindicator
```

to remove tlp

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove tlp
```

to remove tlp UI:

```
sudo apt remove --autoremove tlpui
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me! Thank you very much and stay safe