# Is it possible to improve Battery life & Overheat?

Tags: release-hera, battery, overheat

I am concerned and really disappointed because battery consumption is much more higher than Windows 10 and heat from processor area is worrying and disturbing, same usage, web browsing.
Elementary OS "Hera" @celeron N4000

Answer (score -1):

You can install TLP to improve it. You will find an answer in Google how to install it in Ubuntu. Because Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu repo, you can install the software identical way in Elementary OS like in Ubuntu.

Do not minus answer, just because I wrote the truth above. Anyway solution which I have provided earlier is here:
[how to install TLP and TLPUI](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24223/indicators-on-wingpanel/24233?noredirect=1#comment25535_24233)

So all what was necessary -> to use search here in Stack Exchange.

Comment: Answer edited above and provided a solution.