# Thinkpad L590 overheating problem!

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, overheat

I've used other Linux distros on my Thinkpad but non had this overheating problem when I using it. I've W10 on my machine too, but it's always cool. I've just installed **tlp**, and even **tp_smapi** (even it doesn't include L-series). Has anyone encountered the same problem with a Thinkpad? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I kindly ask you to disable Secure Boot and Trusted Platform Module in BIOS, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution I provided here: [indicators on wingpanel](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24223/indicators-on-wingpanel/24245?noredirect=1#comment25568_24245)

However I cannot guarantee it will solve your issue. But we can try to figure it out, what causes the issue.